# Avoiding echo -e

Tags: shell-script, posix, echo

I would like to store an HTTP request in a variable and then use it with OpenSSL

I now have

```
HTTP_REQUEST="HEAD / HTTP/1.1\\nHost: ${HOST_HEADER}\\nUser-Agent: check_ssl_cert/${VERSION}\\nConnection: close\\n\\n"
```

and then

```
echo -e '${HTTP_REQUEST}' | openssl s_client -connect ${HOST}:${PORT} ${SERVERNAME} -status 2> /dev/null | grep -A 17 'OCSP response:'
```

`echo e` is not POSIX. Is there an alternative?

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

Comment: In addition to the dupe, `echo -e '${HTTP_REQUEST}'` would output the exact string `${HTTP_REQUEST}`, as it's single quoted.